# Socket.io resets React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm running into a weird problem when working with React and Socket.io. Appreciate anyone might be able to help.

**Goal:** 
-->1. socket.io emits an event to react frontend with a list of buttons 
-->2. react renders the list of buttons 
-->3. user clicks on a button
-->4. text on button gets sent as a message
-->5. set state from {hidden: false} to {hidden: true}
-->6. buttons get hidden, so user can't go back and click on them

**Code:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid';

class ButtonsMessage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hidden:false
        };

    }

    handleButtonClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({hidden:true});
        this.props.socket.emit('newMessage', event.target.textContent, this.props.user);
    };

    render() {
        const buttons = this.props.buttons;
        return (
            <li className="message w-100">
                {!this.state.hidden &&
                <div className="row justify-content-center message-content-wrapper">
                    <div className="col-8 message rounded message__body">
                        {
                            buttons.map((button) => {
                                return (
                                    <div
                                        key={uuidv4()}
                                        onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
                                        className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm message-btn">
                                        {button.buttonText}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            </li>
        );
    }
}

export default ButtonsMessage;
```

**Problem:**
Steps 1-4 works fine. But buttons do not get hidden after user clicks on one. When I check the state (in react dev tools) after a button is clicked, the state is still {hidden:false}.[React state screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UvlO.png) I'm suspecting the state gets reset to original state after the this.props.socket.emit line runs.

**Trouble shooting:** 
1. Move setState after socket.emit:  does not work
2. Comment out socket.emit line: DOES hide buttons
3. Add callback in setState:

```js
this.setState({hidden:true}, ()=>{
    console.log(this.state.hidden);
});
```

output:

> true

I'm only including the code i think is relevant. Please let me know if I need to post other parts of the code to help troubleshooting.

THANKS!

Comment: the code you posted looks fine. can you show the component which renders this one? maybe it's getting mounted / unmounted for some reason?  do you have socket listeners somewhere higher up?

Comment: The only scenario i could imagine would be a complete component remount. Try to add a log entry to `onComponentWillUnmount`

Comment: Oh. Are there any errors? Maybe `socket.emit` throws an error that stops JS execution?

Comment: @azium yup that was the problem! I was using uuidv4() to generate a unique key for the component rendering this one. Did some digging and found that will cause the key to being regenerated everytime the component renders, which will lead to remounting of the child component. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @JonasW.  yup that was the problem! See my own answer below. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that in the end your problem had nothing to do with socket.io, and was an issue with react key attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using uuidv4() to generate a unique key for the component rendering this one.

```js
...

return (
  <div key={uuidv4()}>
      {message.buttons && <ButtonsMessage socket={this.props.socket} user={this.props.user} buttons={message.buttons} />}
  </div>
)
...
```

Did some digging and found that will cause the key to being regenerated everytime the component renders, which will lead to remounting of the child component, which in turn resets its state.

I moved the key generation to socket.io server side and pass that key to the component as the unique key and fixed the problem.

```js
<div key={message.messageId}>
    {message.buttons && <ButtonsMessage socket={this.props.socket} user={this.props.user} buttons={message.buttons} />}
</div>
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!