# React context state resets because of Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I looked at some of the similar threads but none of them had a fix for this.

When I click on a channel it sets it to through `setActiveChannel` and `activeChannel` is passed through `ChannelContext`. Everything works correctly, channel object is set to this state. But when I send a message through input => socket server => client and useEffect with `[socket]` is executed `msgListener` cannot read `activeChannel` object, it seems like it goes back to default value of `activeChannel` state which is {}.

Another interesting thing is when I for example add new comment to file and save it, then `activeChannel` state is as it should be and `if (msgData.channelId === activeChannel.channelId)` is true. But when I refresh whole app and start "fresh" firstly opening channel then typing a message, `msgListener` can't get `activeChannel`.

```
  import { ChannelContext } from "../../../context/channel";
  import { socket } from "../../../context/socket";

export default function Chat() {
  const { activeChannel } = useContext(ChannelContext);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState(null);
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Active channel changed");
    console.log(activeChannel.channelId);
    setCurrentState(activeChannel);
    setMessages(activeChannel.messagesByDate);
  }, [activeChannel]);

  const msgListener = (msgData) => {
    console.log("socket message before if: ");
    console.log(msgData.message);
    console.log("activechannel:");
    console.log(activeChannel); // returns {}
    console.log("activechannel id:"); 
    console.log(activeChannel.channelId); //returns undefined

    if (msgData.channelId === activeChannel.channelId) { // therefore not true
      setNewMessage(msgData);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on("message", msgListener);
      return () => socket.off("message", msgListener);
    }
  }, [socket]); 

...
}
```

Here code for setting channel:

```
 const { activeChannel, setActiveChannel } = useContext(ChannelContext);

  const getActiveChannel = async (channelId) => {

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/channel/${channelId}`, config);

      if (data) {
        setActiveChannel(data.channel);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Here parent component with Socket context

```
const [activeChannel, setActiveChannel] = useState({});
    return (
    <div>
      <ChannelContext.Provider value={{ activeChannel, setActiveChannel }}>

          <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            <Dashboard channelItems={channelItems} getChannels={getChannels} />
          </SocketContext.Provider>
      </ChannelContext.Provider>
      {error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
```

socket context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io();

export const SocketContext = createContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it. I have written socket useEffect again:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on("message", (msgData) => {
        if (activeChannel.channelId) {
          if (msgData.channelId === activeChannel.channelId) {
            setNewMessage(msgData);
          }
        }
      });
      return () => socket.off("message");
    }
  }, [socket, messages]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this for other people searching along the terms of " why does socket.io reset my state when .on or other event listeners are used. I want to clarify the above solution.

This turns out to be a simple useEffect() behavior issue and not an issue within socket.io. Although this is the case I feel that socket.io made an oversight not communicating this in their react hooks documentation.

Below is problem code.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (socket) {
   socket.on("message", msgListener);
   return () => socket.off("message", msgListener);
}
}, [socket]);
```

Although it is abstracted to somewhere else in their code, the above code is most likely referencing a state with previously stored messages.

The above useEffect runs a single time at the mounting of this component, and when socket changes. One may deduce that the variables used in writing this useEffect would remain dynamic and run once executed by socket.io, however it is not dynamic, it is static and the useState called in 'message' remains static and at the value it was during the mounting of the parent component.

To reiterate your component mounts and because of [socket] at the the end of useEffect the useEffect runs a single time at component mount. There is abstraction within socket.io in which the callback function ran by .on('message') is saved and the variable values are frozen at the time of mount.

This obviously seems like your state is being reset however that is not the case. You are just using the out dated states.

If you have a socket.io listener that needs to change dynamically based on variables or states that update you need to write a separate use effect with a dependency based on the state you wish to remain dynamic, you MUST also return a socket.off('message') so that the old listener is removed with the old state, everytime your state is updated. If you don't do this, you may also get old out of date states from the previous socket io listener you forgot to remove.

```
let [message,setMessage] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
     if (socket) {
      socket.on("message", msgListener);
      return () => socket.off("message", msgListener);
    }
 }, [socket,message]);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423229/13263977

This is a word for word copy of answer I gave in the above link but slighlty tailored for this question. I think the example code and the solution I give is a little clearer in the link provided if you are still struggling.